# I got a TypeError: mongoose.model is not a function. How do I fix it?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I tried to run it but I get a type error, am I missing something.

```
let CustomerSchema = new mongoose.connect({
useNewUrlParser: true,
name: String,
email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
}
```

})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Customer', CustomerSchema);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you imported the lib yet?

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
```

Comment: Does this count as the same thing. let mongoose = require('mongodb')

Comment: you seem to be importing mongodb not mongoose